# Sklearn pipeline throws ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am trying to create a sklearn pipeline which will first extract the average word length in a text, and then standardize it using `StandardScaler`.

custom transformer

```
class AverageWordLengthExtractor(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def average_word_length(self, text):
        return np.mean([len(word) for word in text.split( )])
    def fit(self, x, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, x , y=None):
        return pd.DataFrame(pd.Series(x).apply(self.average_word_length))
```

My goal is to achieve this. X is a pandas series with text values. This works.

```
    extractor=AverageWordLengthExtractor()
    print(extractor.transform(X[:10]))
    sc=StandardScaler()
    print(sc.fit_transform(extractor.transform(X[:10])))
```

The pipeline I created for this is.

```
pipeline = Pipeline([('text_length', AverageWordLengthExtractor(), 'scale', StandardScaler())])
```

But the `pipeline.fit_transform()` producing below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "custom_transformer.py", line 48, in <module>
    main()
  File "custom_transformer.py", line 43, in main
    'scale', StandardScaler())])
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 114, in __init__
    self._validate_steps()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py", line 146, in _validate_steps
    names, estimators = zip(*self.steps)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Your brackets are in the wrong place when creating the Pipeline, should be `pipeline = Pipeline([('text_length', AverageWordLengthExtractor()), ('scale', StandardScaler())])`

Comment: but it does not work without an estimator in the pipeline. I just wanted to transform the data.

Comment: Do you get the same error? What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: Your answer did work to get rid of one problem :). I would mark it as answered but you did not post it as an answer . Edit : marked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your brackets are in the wrong place / you are missing brackets when creating the Pipeline, should be a list of tuples:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
   ('text_length', AverageWordLengthExtractor()), 
   ('scale', StandardScaler())
])
```

Comment: I am experiencing the same error with my pipeline but my use of brackets are fine. I have also defined some custom estimators that I use in my pipeline as in the example above, only difference is that my estimators are parameterised.

Comment: I can only imagine there is an issue in your custom estimators / how you are parameterising them. I recommend a new question for assistance!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need add `fit_transform` method to your class `AverageWordLengthExtractor`.

Comment: thanks for answering, I was having problem with brackets.